# PHP converting UTC to Local Time

Tags: php, yii, php-carbon

In my postgresql, the I have the following column named "created" that has the type **timestamp with timezone**

So I inserted the record according to the format as such which I believe is UTC.

**2015-10-02 09:09:35+08**

I am using php Carbon library so i did the following:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse('2015-10-02 09:09:35+08');
echo  $date->->toDatetimeString(); 
//gives result as 2015-10-02 09:09:35
```

How can I use the library to echo the correct timezone which includes the adding of the +8 in the above datetime format? The timzezone that I am using is **"Asia/Singapore"**.

The time should be printed to local timing which is 2015-10-02: 17:09:35:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using native php without using Carbon:

```
$time = '2015-10-02 16:34:00+08';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s+O', $time);
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore'));
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Etc/UTC'));
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Deza: in my postgres the string format is 2015-10-02 09:09:35+08. I need to convert tat utc timing to local timing. Ur example doesn't explain the xase of +08.

Comment: Let me give tat a try for the benefit of doubt :)

Comment: Edited the answer, hope it makes sense. Not sure which way around the timezones are, but hopefully you can see how it's supposed to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$timestamp = '2015-10-02 16:34:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Asia/Singapore');
```

Comment: Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Asia/Singapore');

That line of code just throws an error

Comment: If you are having issues you can have a look at Carbon documentation here: 
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Comment: Before posting a question here, i did my search at the api. I cudnt find. All i need is, with the current utc time, i want to print the local time by adding the +08. However i dun see the method or have missed

Comment: Can you share the error from above code or result of it ?

Secondly, did you tried to use Carbon addHours method? e.g.
Carbon::now()->addHours(8);

Comment: Will try the addHrs. That is the last result i could take. I left my work station n will update u soon

Answer (score 1):

Try this using standard PHP:

```
$raw = '2015-10-02 09:09:35+08';
$date = substr($raw,0,19);
$tzOffset = (strlen($raw) > 19) ? substr($raw,-3) : 0;
$timestamp = strtotime($date) + (60 * 60 * $tzOffset);
$localTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$timestamp);
echo 'local time:['.$localTime.']';
```

The result is:

```
local time:[2015-10-02 17:09:35]
```

This will also work without a time zone offset or a negative one.