# Twitter API - Get tweets from last 24 hours or last hour

Tags: php, api, twitter, web-deployment

Im working with the Twitter API and havent found out how to get the tweets from only the last hour for example?

I cannot figure it out how to get tweets only from last 24 or from last 1 hour.. Can someone help me?

Here is my script. This script counts the tweets currently but from last 7 days as normal...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIClass/TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "XXXXX",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "YYYYY",
    'consumer_key' => "XXXX",
    'consumer_secret' => "YYYY"
);


$query = '%24synx';
$max_id = 0;
$tweets_count = 0;

while (true) {
  // First API call
  if ($max_id == 0) {
    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
    $getfield = "?q=".$query."&count=100";
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $twitter_data = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(), true);

   // Repeated API call
   } else {
    // Collect older tweets
    --$max_id;

    $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
    $getfield = "?q=".$query."&count=100&max_id=".$max_id."";
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $twitter_data = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->performRequest(), true);
  }          

$tweets = $twitter_data['statuses'];

print_r($tweets);

// Exit loop when no more tweets are returned
if (sizeof($tweets)==0) {
    break;
  }

    // Count tweets
    foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
    ++$tweets_count;
    $max_id = $tweet['id'];
  } 

//Sleep 3 seconds after every API call, to not exceed API rate limit
sleep(3);  
}


echo $tweets_count;      
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this loop

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
    ++$tweets_count;
    $max_id = $tweet['id'];
}
```

Check the date/time of the tweet (`$tweet['created_at']`). When the value is more than 24 hours old exit the outer `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks. How to do that properly? The Twitter "created_at" date format seems quite strange.. :/

Comment: It is UTC time (Greenwich mean time). So, either convert it to your local time, or convert your local time to UTC. What seems strange?

Comment: Hmm whats the best way to convert it to my time? Thanks alot.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904530/php-converting-utc-to-local-time